# How to get the sum of a value in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I've a mysql table `properties` with these records:

```
---------------------------------
    id        value
---------------------------------
    1           1
    1             1
    2             1
    2             1
    1             1
---------------------------------
```

Now, I want to query to output:

```
----------------------------
    id           value
----------------------------
     1            3
     2            2
----------------------------
```

Comment: `select id,sum(value) as value group by id`

Comment: Not too nice way of asking a question...

Comment: Is that the sum, or number of value per id... they both have the same answer ergo impossible to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select id,sum(value) as value FROM table group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GROUP BY` parameter.

```
SELECT id, SUM(value) as value FROM tablename GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I don't get why this has been downvoted? It's a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```
SELECT id, sum(value) AS value FROM `tablename ` Group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is what you want:

```
select id, sum(value) as value from properties group by id
```